# Tick bite treatment. Doxycycline intake suspended after 3 days only. If substituted by Bactrim, is there a risk to develop bacteria resistant?

Tags: medications, bacteria, antibiotics, antibacterial-resistance

A patient was bitten by a tick and carried the tick on his skin for 5/6 days (which got engorged at the end).
Then the tick dropped spontaneously.
He has been prescribed a preventive antibiotic course of 3 weeks with doxycycline 100mg.
After only 3 days he dismissed the antibiotic intake, due to strong gastric reaction.
He has been prescribed a new antibiotic course of Bactrim 80/400 mg (trimethoprim/sulfamethoxazole).
Due to the different mechanism of action of doxycycline in respect to Bactrim, can the patient develop a bacterial strain resistant to doxycycline?